# Call API on Checkbox in react-native

Tags: react-native

when i click on checkbox call API For posting question and in my API i'm gonna Passing param's username and userimage HOW TO DO  THIS

Answer (score 0):

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/checkbox.html#onvaluechange

call your api call in `onvaluechange` prop

and check for its value from state or redux